# Windows 10 - Stop Lock Screen from Sleeping

Tags: windows-10, sleep

We'd like the Windows 10 lock screen to remain on all the time (or at least for a couple of hours) so that the picture remains visible. This is for aesthetic reasons.

When the PC is locked (i.e. user logged on, station locked), it seems to turn off the screen signal after a minute or so has elapsed. Moving the cursor wakes it.

Changing the corresponding setting in Power Options doesn't seem to impact how the lock screen behaves. Does anybody have any suggestions?

It seems to not sleep the screen if you have powered up the PC and not yet logged on.

Comment: Since you have tried to configure the power options within Windows, have you confirmed, the monitors themselfs don't have a power saving mode you need to configure?  Is this PC connected to an Active Domain?

Comment: It is on a domain, and it isn't the monitor itself (the monitor displays 'no signal' when the pc switches off display)

Comment: Configure all applicable group policies to your desired values (i.e. not `not configured`) then pushed a group policy update.

Comment: It didn't do this prior to the latest Windows 10 update?

Comment: Was update that a feature update, but irregardless of that, have you verified all your settings?